# What is this PHP process? It is crippling my server

Tags: php, mysql

This process has been using 65% of my site CPU and has lasted for about 10 minutes now (aren't processes only supposed to go for a couple seconds?)

It is obviously something with mysql. This makes sense because I have a lot of queries going, but something still seems a bit odd...

This could have something to do with my bad PDO connection that I mentioned in the previous question. Perhaps I am opening too many connections or something like that?

Here is the stats on it:

```
Owner: mysql
Priority: 0
CPU %: 61.1
Memory %: 0.4
Command:/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/cvps54834319.myhost.com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/cvps54834319.myhost.com.pid
```

Thanks for any help on this. I have over 10GHZ on my server so this is very concerning to me.

Comment: Good question, may be better answered on ServerFault.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary ``served`` was also right word :D

Comment: 60% CPU usage from MySQL is not suspicious to me.

Comment: Run this query: `show process list;`. It will tell you which queries are running and for how long.

Comment: just kill it and see if something breaks.

Comment: I tried that, but it popped right back up again with a new PID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this file

```
/var/lib/mysql/cvps54834319.myhost.com.err
```

you will see what is going on and what isnot working and what is causing this problem

Comment: Thanks...trying this now...will get back to you.